# How can I read all of the paragraphs of a text into a list?

Tags: java, text-processing, text-parsing

I'm trying to break a text into its various paragraphs. I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188265/what-character-can-be-used-to-parse-for-paragraphs-with-java) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155836/java-how-to-use-scanner-to-read-and-count-paragraph) question. However, I've already figured out how to detect the paragraphs. I'm having trouble saving them.

```
One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found
himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin.  He lay on
his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could
see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff
sections.  The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready
to slide off any moment.  His many legs, pitifully thin compared
with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he
looked.

"What's happened to me?" he thought.  It wasn't a dream.  His room,
a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully
between its four familiar walls.  A collection of textile samples
```

The text above would be counted as two paragraphs. Below is the function that I am using for paragraph detection.

```
public List<Paragraph> findParagraph(List<String> originalBook)
{
    List<Paragraph> paragraphs = new LinkedList<Paragraph>();
    List<String> sentences = new LinkedList<String>();


    for(int i=0;i<originalBook.size();i++)
    {
        //if it isn't a blank line
        //don't count I,II symbols
        if(!originalBook.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("") & originalBook.get(i).length()>2)
        {
            sentences.add(originalBook.remove(i));

            //if the line ahead of where you are is a blank line you've reach the end of the paragraph
            if(i < originalBook.size()-1)
            {
                if(originalBook.get(i+1).equalsIgnoreCase("") )
                {
                    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
                    List<String> strings = sentences;
                    paragraph.setSentences(strings);
                    paragraphs.add(paragraph);
                    sentences.clear();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return paragraphs;
}
```

And this is the class that defines my Paragraph

```
public class Paragraph
{

    private List<String> sentences;

    public Paragraph()
    {
        super();
    }


    public List<String> getSentences() {
        return sentences;
    }

    public void setSentences(List<String> sentences) {
        this.sentences = sentences;
    }

}
```

I'm able to detect the paragraphs fine, but I'm clearing all of the sentences and I'm getting a list that only contains the last paragraph. I've been trying to think of a solution and I haven't been able to come up with one. Can anybody offer any advice?

I've tried to be as thorough as possible in my explanation. I can add more details if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in this block:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
List<String> strings = sentences; // <-- !!!!!
paragraph.setSentences(strings);
paragraphs.add(paragraph);
sentences.clear();
```

You use the *same* object that `sentences` points to for all your paragraphs, so in the end all your `Paragraph` objects will point to the *same* `List<String>`. Thus, any change you make to `sentences` will alter that single `List<String>`, and the changes will be seen across all your `Paragraph` objects, as they all refer to the same instance.

It's a little like if `sentences` were a balloon, what you're doing is giving all your `Paragraph` objects a string leading to that balloon (plus another string leading back to `sentences`). If one of those objects (or the `sentences` reference) decides to follow the string and pop the balloon, everyone will see the change.

The solution is simple. Skip `sentences.clear()` and simply use `List<String> strings = new LinkedList<>()` instead of `List<String> strings = sentences`. That way, all your `Paragraph` objects will have *distinct* `List<String>` objects that hold their sentences, and changes you make to any one of them will be independent of the other. If you do that, you can skip declaring `sentences` at the beginning of the method too.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to be more efficient and clean, rather than calculating its index and creating multiple if statements.

**sample:**

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
String parag = "";

while(scan.hasNextLine())
{
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    if(s.trim().length() != 0)
        parag += s + "\n"; //new sentence
    else
    {
        System.out.println(parag); //new paragraph
        parag = "";
    }
}

System.out.println(parag); //last paraggraph
```